# smali (Android): Operating on an Instance Variable

Tags: android, smali

i'm trying to do the following using smali:

1. add a private instance `ArrayList` field to a class
2. instantiate the instance field in the class' constructor
3. do an `add` operation on the field in one of the class' methods.

These are the relevant code snippets. (My class name is `com.mypackage.MyClass` (i.e. `com/mypackage/MyClass`))

In the `# instance fields` section of the smali code, i added the line

```
.field private myList:Ljava/util/List;
```

In the public constructor method (`.method public constructor <init>()V`), i added the lines

```
new-instance v1, Ljava/util/ArrayList;
invoke-direct {v1}, Ljava/util/ArrayList;-><init>()V
iput-object v1, p0, Lcom/mypackage/MyClass;->myList:Ljava/util/List;
```

And finally, in the instance methods where i want to perform the `add` method calls, i added the lines

```
iget-object v6, p0, Lcom/mypackage/MyClass;->myList:Ljava/util/List;
invoke-interface {v6, v3}, Ljava/util/List;->add(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
invoke-interface {v6, v4}, Ljava/util/List;->add(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
```

However, the line

```
iget-object v6, p0, Lcom/mypackage/MyClass;->myList:Ljava/util/List;
```

gives me the error (according to logcat)

```
10-29 15:47:58.999: W/dalvikvm(518): VFY: 'this' arg 'Ljava/util/List;' not instance of 'Lcom/mypackage/MyClass;'
```

I compared what I did with a similar method call in the same method, and couldn't figure out what was wrong.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The p0 register contains the "this" reference when the method enters, but anything can modify it afterwards. Based on that error message, it looks like the p0 regsiter has a List object in it, at the point where the iget-object is.

Comment: OF COURSE! argh... what a **STUPID** mistake... i had increased the `.registers` declaration from 6 to 7, then _conveniently_ just used the last one (`v6`) for the temporary purpose for my `iget-object`. but of course, `v6` **IS** `p0` and i should be using `v5` instead!